# How to save JPG data to SD correctly

Tags: c++, c, arduino

```
#include <LSY201.h>
#include <SD.h>

/* assuming the TX and RX pins on the camera are attached to pins 2 and 3 of
 * the arduino. */

#define camera_serial Serial1  //Tells library to use Serial1
LSY201 camera;
uint8_t buf[32];

const int chipSelect_SD_default = 51;  //SS pin for WF32
const int chipSelect_SD = chipSelect_SD_default;

File myFile;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(38400);
 camera.setSerial(camera_serial);
 camera_serial.begin(38400);

 pinMode(chipSelect_SD, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(chipSelect_SD, HIGH);

 if (!SD.begin(chipSelect_SD)) {
   Serial.println("initialization failed!");
   return;
  }
 Serial.println("initialization done.");
 Serial.println("Taking picture...");
 camera.takePicture();
 delay(3000);

 Serial.println("Bytes:");


 myFile = SD.open("testpic.jpg", FILE_WRITE);
 uint16_t offset = 0;
 while (camera.readJpegFileContent(offset, buf, sizeof(buf)))
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i ++)
     myFile.println(buf[i], HEX);

   offset += sizeof(buf);
 }
 myFile.close();

 Serial.println("Done.");


 camera.stopTakingPictures();
 delay(10000);
}
```

I'm using UART hardware serial on a WF32, compiling on the Arduino IDE. Data is correct but I dont know how to save the data in a correct JPG format so I can view the image just by opening testpic.jpg.

Camera Module: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10061

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to save it directly? Of course you can't use the `println` function, because you need to put binary data. Replace `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i ++)
     myFile.println(buf[i], HEX);` with `myFile.write(buff, sizeof(buff));`. I think, however, that there are some problems with the end of the image, so the library should be modified. But anyway before modifying it try to simply write it and check if it works..

Comment: It worked! Your truly a lifesaver man. There is a small amount of error at the EOI but it's almost unnoticeable in the image. I'm new to this forum can I vouch you somehow?

Comment: Glad it worked :) The error probably is done by the library (when it arrives at the end of the image it goes on reading; it should stop and report back the actual size). Anyway I don't know if you can upvote the comment, but anyhow I'm happy I could help you :)